# IAT Hooking for testings

Tags: c++, dll, hook

I am trying to hook a function to cmd.exe process
the dll is injected just fine the problem is i can't get the cmd.exe to call my function
when im trying to enter the word "dir" on the command prompt it's showing me the same results instade of changing the first name to 'dan'
what am i doing wrong?

```
HANDLE WINAPI newFindFirstFileA(__in   LPCTSTR lpFileName, __out  LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData) 
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(lpFileName, &FindFileData);
    *FindFileData.cFileName = L'Dan';
    lpFindFileData = &FindFileData;
    return hFind;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                       DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                       LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ )
{
    switch (reason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(NULL,L"DLL Was injected!", L"Message" ,NULL);

        /* Hooking function */
        DWORD* dw = (DWORD*)GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "FindFirstFileA" );
        *dw = (DWORD)newFindFirstFileA;
        break;
    }  

    /* Returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetProcAddress` does not return the pointer to IAT entry. Instead, it returns the location of the actual function. Thus, `*dw = (DWORD) newFindFirstFileA` would overwrite the prolog of the `FindFirstFileA` function, which would be disastrous. Refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) article for detailed explanation for hooking an API

Comment: thank you for your answer so what is the right way to get the pointer to the IAT entry ?

Comment: Did you read the article and look at the source code there? it basically involves calling `ImageDirectoryEntryToData` with `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT`, looking up the function then replacing the value. Download the source code and see what it's doing

Comment: I was trying to make it work but looks like one of the ImageDirectoryEntryToData function parameters is the base address of the image .. how can i get that address ?

Comment: yes i have read the article but the code is huge and i wasn't able to understand how you get the base address